# Display mayavi X3D figure in different cells in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mayavi

I want to use mayavi to display several 3D figures in Jupyter notebook. To test it, I tried the following example with only 3 cells:

```
# first cell
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.init_notebook('x3d')

# second cell
mlab.test_plot3d()

# third cell
mlab.test_points3d()
```

I noticed several problems when I played with this example:

a) When I run these cells for the first time, the output of the second is good while the third output shows an overlap of two 3D figures. Also after I repeatedly run the second and third cells many times, at some time, the output just crashes and shows something like:

7 0.945098 0.603922,\n 0.866667 0.945098 0.603922,\n 0.866667 0.945098 0.603922,\n 0.847059 0.937255 0.607843,\n 0.847059 0.937255 0.607843,\n 0.847059 0.937255 0.607843,\n 0.847059 0.937255 0.607843,\n 0.847059 0.937255 0.607843,\n 0.847059 0.937255 0.607843,\n 0.819608 0.929412...

as well as the follwoing error message:

```
Javascript error adding output!

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

b) I tried to fixed the overlap problem by add **mlab.figure()** to the beginning of the second and third cell:

```
# second cell
mlab.figure()
mlab.test_plot3d()

# third cell
mlab.figure()
mlab.test_points3d()
```

which indeed gives me separate figures when I run these cells for the first time. However, when I want to repeat the cells, I run into the same problem as shown above.

c) Just for comparison, I remove the third cell and just keep the second cell. This time, if I use the following code for the second cell

```
# second cell
mlab.test_plot3d()
```

It never has this crash problem. However, if I add **mlab.figure()** to it, repeatedly running it gives me the same problem.

So my question is: is there a way to get more robust mayavi output in Jupyter notebook, i.e., regenerate the object and display it every time when I run a cell again? I'm still new to mayavi, so any solution just based on **mlab** is greatly appreciated. However, if that's impossible, then solutions using more complicated methods in mayavi (like building the pipeline manually) is also welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `mayavi.mlab.clf` to clear figures before creating a new figure. The document of this function is [there](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_figure.html#clf) .

I believe it make sense to use this function before each new figure even it is the first figure, such as:

```py
# first cell
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.init_notebook('x3d')

# second cell
mlab.clf()
mlab.test_plot3d()

# third cell
mlab.clf()
mlab.test_points3d()
```

Comment: In my case setting the rendering option to `mlab.init_notebook('png')` helped as well